# Como buscar elementos en jquery o javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

la verdad es que no sabia que titulo ponerle a la pregunta igual es un poco "general". Veran tengo un pequeño problema el código es el siguiente:

```js
var a = $("section:visible").prevAll('.titulo').first();
alert($(a).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="p1" style="display:none" class="titulo">titulo1</section>
<section id="p2" style="display:none" class="slide">1a</section>
<section id="p3" style="display:block" class="slide">1a</section>

<section id="p4" style="display:none" class="titulo">titulo2</section>
<section id="p5" style="display:none" class="slide">2b</section>
<section id="p6" style="display:none" class="slide">2b</section>

<section id="p7" style="display:none" class="titulo">titulo3</section>
<section id="p8" style="display:block" class="slide">3c</section>
<section id="p9" style="display:none" class="slide">3c</section>
```

Vale lo que necesito es que en el alert muestre titulo1 y titulo3 ya que lo que busco es que todas las clases que son slide (en este caso #p3 y #p8) que están visibles muestre el primer .titulo que hay antes. Y no se porque titulo3 lo muestra pero titulo1 no, me imagino que porque .first() detiene la ejecución.

Gracias de antemano.

PD: me da igual resolverlo mediante javscript puro o jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Principalmente el problema es que en tu HTML no hay ninguna jerarquía, por lo tanto se haría difícil determinar *cuál es el elemento que posee la clase `titulo` dentro de un grupo de elementos previamente seleccionados por algún otro criterio*.

Si por ejemplo, organizamos los grupos de elementos dentro de un elemento padre (un `div` en este caso), el trabajo se haría fácil:

1. Pasamos a una selección más directa: escogemos aquellos elementos cuyo estilo sea `display:block`
2. Luego, dado que tenemos un elemento padre (el `div`), buscamos en él el elemento que tiene la clase `titulo`, mediante `querySelector`

Todo el código usado es Javascript puro. Espero te sea de utilidad.

```js
var elBlock = document.querySelectorAll('[style="display:block"]');

elBlock.forEach(function(el) {
  elTitle = el.parentNode.querySelector(".titulo");
  console.log(elTitle.textContent);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <section id="p1" style="display:none" class="titulo">titulo1</section>
  <section id="p2" style="display:none" class="slide">1a</section>
  <section id="p3" style="display:block" class="slide">1a</section>
</div>
<div>
  <section id="p4" style="display:none" class="titulo">titulo2</section>
  <section id="p5" style="display:none" class="slide">2b</section>
  <section id="p6" style="display:none" class="slide">2b</section>
</div>
<div>
  <section id="p7" style="display:none" class="titulo">titulo3</section>
  <section id="p8" style="display:block" class="slide">3c</section>
  <section id="p9" style="display:none" class="slide">3c</section>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. Al principio tambien contemple esa solución y creo que va a ser la que voy a tomar,lo intente evitar porque tenia que toquetear mucho css para hacer eso pero a la larga creo que es mejor